# How to scan entire line in php?

Tags: php

I'm trying to scan an entire line but my code takes only the first character and then jumps to the next line. Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
<?php
$n_matrix_val=4;
for ($y = 1; $y <= $n_matricx_val; $y++) {
   fscanf(STDIN ,"%s\n", $the_matricx_val);
   fwrite(STDOUT, $the_matricx_val);
}
```

My input is:

```
5 8 9 7
3 4 9 8
1 5 4 9
3 2 7 6
```

and my out put is:

```
5313
```

I'm very new at this I'm trying solve small problems please help

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: im trying to scan the entire matrix but it takes onlny the first value in the matrix

Comment: "%s\n" is causing the issue, your newline should be out side the loop I guess

Comment: actually i have couple of more matrices in the input so i want only one matrix to be scanned at a time so it has to be inside the loop

Comment: could it be because `$n_matrix_val = 4`? there is only four values in a row. so maybe try making the value 1? just guessing here..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern is worng. Try this.

```
$n_matrix_val = 4;
for ($y = 1; $y <= $n_matrix_val; $y++)
    {
    $the_matricx_val = fscanf(STDIN, "%s %s %s %s");
    fwrite(STDOUT, implode(' ', $the_matricx_val) . PHP_EOL);
    }
```

But if you want to read whole line just use `fgets`.

```
    $the_matricx_val = fgets(STDIN);
    fwrite(STDOUT, $the_matricx_val);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `"%[^\n]s"` to get whole line:

```
$n_matricx_val=4;

for($y=1;$y<=$n_matricx_val;$y++)
{
    fscanf(STDIN ,"%[^\n]s", $the_matricx_val);
    fwrite(STDOUT, $the_matricx_val . "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do :

```
<?php 
    $i=trim(fgets(STDIN));
?>
```

This code will get you the whole line.